# Pass function call as attribute in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

My Polymer element has an array attribute with anywhere from 1-10,000 items, so I need to generate it when the element is instantiated.  However, I would **really** like to pass in an array using a function call or reference:

```
<script>
  function genArray(size){
    var a = [];
    for(var i = 0, count = size - 1; i < count; i++){
      a.push("domain" + count + ".tld");
    }
    return a;
  }
</script>

<my-element domains="genArray()"></my-element>
```

Or reference a global object.

```
<script>
  function genArray(size){
    var a = [];
    for(var i = 0, count = size - 1; i < count; i++){
      a.push("domain" + count + ".tld");
    }
    return a;
  }

  window.myArray = genArray(1000);
</script>

<my-element domains="window.myArray"></my-element>
```

I've tried variations on quote style (`""` vs `''`) brackets (`"{{genArray}}"`) and I even `'{"array":window.myArray}'`.

I understand that I could pass in the parameter or a reference to a global object and process them in a lifecycle callback.  However, it would be much cleaner and simplify testing/deployment if I could pass in a call to an external function.  Am I just screwed until template strings comes along in ES7?

Answer (score 0):

Bindings only work within the Polymer environment, but there is a solution!  Polymer provides a helper component called `dom-bind` that you can use anywhere in a page, even outside of a Polymer element:

```
<script>
  function genArray() {
      ...
  }

  window.myArray = genArray(1000);
</script>
<template is="dom-bind">
  <my-element domains="[[myArray]]"></my-element>
</template>
```

More documentation for this component can be found at https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind

Comment: Are you sure you have the syntax correct?  Polymer is no longer throwing warnings about not being able to parse as an array, but now my 'domains' object is just undefined....

Comment: Another question, won't linking to the Polymer library mess with statically built/Vulcanized Polymer Elements?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in an environment where I can check that syntax, but it does occur to me that `dom-bind` bindings would would be looking for properties on the `dom-bind` element itself, rather than `window`.  Try giving the `template` an ID, then change the assignment to `document.querySelector('#my-id').myArray = genArray(1000);`

Comment: You would also have to move the `script` after the `template` in the DOM, or ensure it executes after the DOM has loaded.